# How to implement timed autoscroll and position markers in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` in Android. I want to implement an auto scroll feature in it such that it will go to the next view every five seconds. The `RecyclerView` should also contain circular position markers like in the Amazon Prime Video app which will be on top of the images and will show a different colour for the current view. How do I implement this?

[image: Amazon Prime Video Promo Banners]

Comment: why don't you use https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: @DivyeshPatel it can also done with TimerTask what do you think...?

Comment: yes, but it is easy to use above instead of writing recycleview and timer.. and it has various animations

Comment: i am not saying that your code is wrong, just he don't need to write recycle view and timer and markers. Above library does that job with 5 line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  **[TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)**

> A task that can be scheduled for one-time or repeated execution by a Timer.

```
Timer timer;
public int position =0;
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, 2000); // delay*/

 private class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

@Override
public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           if(position==arraylist.size()){
              position=0;
              position++
           else{
              position++
           }
           recyclerview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position).

         // or use
          recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition( position)
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: you need to deaclare `public int position =0;` to start from 0 postion

Comment: I want the circles on top on the recycler view like in the photo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library for automatic time interval image sliding:--

```
<ss.com.bannerslider.views.BannerSlider
android:id="@+id/banner_slider1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

[Follow this link for more info](https://github.com/saeedsh92/Banner-Slider?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5168)